# calculate sum of each td having similar class

Tags: jquery, html, sum, html-table

My html table td looks like this

```
<td class="20">1</td>
<td class="20">2</td>
<td class="20">3</td>
<td class="20">4</td>
<td class="20">5</td>
<td class="20">3</td>
<td class="total"></td>
<td class="30">2</td>
<td class="30">5</td>
<td class="30">6</td>
<td class="total"></td>
```

I'm trying to count the number of `td's` available before class `total` and sum the values and put it in respective total class td.

So i want to get

```
<td class="20">1</td>
<td class="20">2</td>
<td class="20">3</td>
<td class="20">4</td>
<td class="20">5</td>
<td class="20">3</td>
<td class="total">Total : 18</td>
<td class="30">2</td>
<td class="30">5</td>
<td class="30">6</td>
<td class="total">Total : 13</td>
```

This is what i have tried.

```
var sum = 0;
$('.total').each(function(){
var tdTxt = $(this).prev('td').text();
    sum += parseFloat(tdTxt);                       
});
```

But it doesnt work. how to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
var temp = 0;
$('td').each(function(){

var tdTxt = $(this).text();
     if($(this).hasClass('total')) {
         $(this).text(temp);
         temp = 0;
    } else {
       temp+= parseFloat(tdTxt);    
    } 

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8f4b1tok/

Answer (score 4):

After seeing your update, I could go with [prevUntil](http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil) solution:

```
$('.total').each(function(){//To calculate with
  var sum = 0;//initialize sum equal to 0
  var fields = $(this).prevUntil('.total');//find the required tds until the .total
  fields.each(function(){//loop each total fields
    sum += parseFloat($(this).text());//add each tds value to sum
  });
$(this).html('<b>The total is: ' + sum + '</b>');//push the value of sum to .total field
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dox114ff/

Answer (score 4):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.total').each(function() {
    var prevClass = $(this).prev().attr('class');
    var sum = 0;
    $('.' + prevClass).each(function() {
      sum += Number($(this).text());
    })

    $(this).text('Total :'+sum);
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="20">1</td>
    <td class="20">2</td>
    <td class="20">3</td>
    <td class="20">4</td>
    <td class="20">5</td>
    <td class="20">3</td>
    <td class="total">8</td>
    <td class="30">2</td>
    <td class="30">5</td>
    <td class="30">6</td>
    <td class="total"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since jQuery provided [`.prevUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/) API to traverse previous sibling until met the element to stop with, use it like so :

```
$('.total').each(function() {

  var sum = 0,
      elem = $(this).prevUntil('.total');

  elem.each(function() {
     sum += parseInt($(this).text())
  });

  $(this).text('Total :' + sum);

});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/t65toyfy/)

Answer (score 2):

Either try .prevAll() function.Find documentation in following links :

http://api.jquery.com/prevall/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_prevall.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `prevUntil` to navigate back to the previous `siblings` of the `td` till a selector, DOM, etc.. One can read more about `prevUntil` [here](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/).

Please find the working demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/rem6zn3u/).

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="20">1</td>
            <td class="20">2</td>
            <td class="20">3</td>
            <td class="20">4</td>
            <td class="20">5</td>
            <td class="20">3</td>
            <td class="total"></td>
            <td class="30">2</td>
            <td class="30">5</td>
            <td class="30">6</td>
            <td class="total"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.total').each(function () {
        var numbers = $(this).prevUntil('.total').text().split('');
        var total = 0;
        $.each(numbers, function (k, v) {
            total += parseInt(v);
        });
        $(this).text('[Total = ' + total + ']');
        console.log('total=', total);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
$('.total').each(function() { 
    var sum = $(this).prevUntil('.total').map(function() { 
        return parseInt($(this).text()); 
    }).get().reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

    $(this).text('Total : ' + sum);
});
```